# C# - Creating synchronous function that uses asynchronous function

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I'm using Amazon's S3 Cloud Object Storage to store files from my application. And I need to increase performance of the file uploading/downloading. From what I've seen, S3 doesn't allow you to do a GetObjects that allows you to download multiple files at once. So my idea is to create a function returns its data synchronously, but it runs asynchronously. Basically, download the files in parallel, but only return the list of files only when all the files have been downloaded.

I don't work with C# that much so I'll work some pseudo code to try to make to make it more clear:

```
GetObjects(listOfObjectKeys){ 
        byte listOfFiles; 
        foreach (int i in listOfObjectKeys) {
             listOfFiles.append((async)S3.GetObject(listOfObjectKeys[i]));
        }  
        return listOfFiles;  
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Edit: forgot to add that the S3.GetObject is not an asynchronous function, I just want to know if I can call it multiple times in parallel instead of having to wait for the previous call to be over

Comment: With the edit: `Parallel.ForEach`

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing (with the `async` etc in the example) is "sync over async", and the only correct guidance is "don't do that". If you need to call async methods: the calling code must be async - it really is as simple as that. Note also that async and parallelism are separate concepts - there is some tangential overlap, but not as much as you'd think. If what you're trying to do is *parallelism*, then: `Parallel.ForEach` etc may be useful, in the case of synchronous code. If you are talking about async code, then there are methods like `Parallel.ForEachAsync`. For downloads to a single backend, parallelism may or may not provide an increase in performance; if you're throttled by bandwidth on the same link, then the additional overheads may actually marginally *reduce* throughput (or perhaps more likely: you may get a *tiny* bit more throughput, but not enough to sing about).